# How to make parts of text fields non-editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a requirement similar to facebook's send message To: text field wherein after you input some value, it will give you the suggestion once you select the suggestion that to field will be still editable but the selected value becomes non editable (you'll have to remove it completely and enter new value to change.) How to do this using JavaScript/jquery?

Comment: Who the hell upvoted this? If you can understand what this question is after you're a better man than I.

Comment: I wish i could have posted the image to make u clear. Please visit this site and try to co-relate http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
The multiple select method

Comment: +1 for understanding question :D

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question and for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery autocoplete
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/